# Copy text from iOS 9 simulator

Tags: ios9

I cannot seems to be able to copy text from the simulator (to the Mac pasteboard) in any way.
Tried to use the CMD-C and the 'copy' popup in the simulator and all combination of the two.
I can paste in the simulator but cannot 'export' that text in any way to the Mac.
I can paste *from* the Mac clipboard (to the simulator), but cannot do the reverse.

Comment: Yup this seems to be broken. I'd file a bug report if I thought someone at Apple would ever read it.

Comment: Actually, I did a few day ago (filed a bug). They have reply back in the past, not all bug, but some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be woking again on latest Xcode (7.3.1)